# Has PHP replaced SSI and CGI?

Tags: php, cgi, ssi

I have been asked to write a web application with SSI or CGI and I was wondering would that mean I would be working with obselete technologies? I don't know much about the history of SSI or CGI but I see basically no job listings on indeed.co.uk for either of them. I see tens of thousands for PHP. Am I correct in saying that PHP has now effectively replaced those technologies?

Am I correct in saying that PHP is a superset of those technologies as it can do absolutely everything they can and more?

Comment: You're correct in saying that you have observed more job listings for PHP than for CGI, yes.  And I agree with that observation.  However, I fail to see the real point of the question.  If I were tasked with building a go-cart, I could argue that an automobile would provide more functionality.  But why?

Comment: If you were looking for a career in automobile design and development and you were tasked with building a go-cart using a hammer, nails and a few pieces of wood do you think it would be worth your while to take the go-cart building task on? I am looking for some information on if and why PHP has superseded those technologies so I can explain precisely why it would not be worth my while doing the web application using them.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a place for career advice.  You _might_ have better luck on Programmers.SE, but you'll want to check the FAQ first (and potentially re-work the question a bit).

Comment: You know: PHP is a programming language, CGI is an interface (even PHP can provide an CGI interface ;)) and SSI a even more a completely different technology. You can use every 3 together :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP can match SSI and CGI feature-wise. I think CGI might have slight performance increases over vanilla PHP, but with a proper Opcode cache like APC PHP would probably beat them in that to.

Some companies still use CGI for legacy reasons, but it isn't a good skill to get a job with anymore.

There are also alternatives to PHP, such as Python + mod_wsgi, Node.js, Ruby + Ruby on Rails, ASP, JSP and more. PHP just happens to be the most popular at this point in time, for web development.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Yes, PHP can be compiled as CGI program. I was more referring to Perl or C CGI binaries, the kind that you see with URLs of /cgi-bin/sendmail.cgi

Comment: ah, I get what you mean now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the main reasons CGI has been replaced by PHP and other scripting languages is that people prefer lightweight frameworks. In CGI each command starts a process on the server so it's inherently much heavier than something like PHP, Perl, etc. Also the simplicity of being able to "lift" a PHP folder from the file system drop it somewhere else and it works, almost without dependency on the server infrastructure. As for SSI, I think it's still in use here and there, but it's a very simple language which doesn't even support loops. CGI/SSI and the like are not only outdated but also functionally inferior, in the long term you will find it easier to work with more modern technologies.